# App asks Read Phone State Permission without any declaration in Manifest file

Tags: android, android-studio, android-permissions, android-debug, android-studio-4.0

There is already a question related to this question. But that didn't help. The answer was more than a decade old. So please don't mark this question as a duplicate.

I can't figure out how my app is asking for this permission.

Here is my `AndroidManifest.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.emptysheet.pdfreader_autoscroll">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>

    <application
        android:name=".PdfReaderApp"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/themeForApp">
        <activity
            android:name=".homeScreen.MainActivity"
            android:theme="@style/themeForApp"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".pdfScreen.PdfActivity" android:theme="@style/pdfViewTheme">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                <data android:scheme="file" />
                <data android:scheme="content"/>
                <data android:mimeType="application/pdf" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".settingScreen.SettingActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"/>

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.APPLICATION_ID"
            android:value="ca-app-pub-5096717122607652~4262160240"/>

        <provider
            android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
            android:authorities="${applicationId}.provider"
            android:exported="false"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                android:resource="@xml/provider_paths"/>
        </provider>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

My App's `build.gradle`

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
apply plugin: 'com.google.firebase.crashlytics'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'
apply plugin: 'dagger.hilt.android.plugin'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.3"


    buildFeatures{
        viewBinding = true
        dataBinding = true
    }



    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.emptysheet.pdfreader_autoscroll"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 7
        versionName "1.7"
        multiDexEnabled true

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

// To inline the bytecode built with JVM target 1.8 into
// bytecode that is being built with JVM target 1.6. (e.g. navArgs)


    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = "1.8"
    }

}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"

    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.3.0'
    implementation "androidx.fragment:fragment-ktx:1.2.5"
    implementation "androidx.activity:activity:1.1.0"

    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.2.0"
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-ktx:2.2.0"
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:2.2.0"
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-savedstate:2.2.0"

    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.preference:preference:1.1.1'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment:2.2.2'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-ui:2.2.2'

    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.2.0'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:2.2.2'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:2.2.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'

    implementation project(path: ':android-pdf-viewer')

    //firebase for crashlytics
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-ktx:17.4.3'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics:17.1.0'
    // for ads
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:19.2.0'
    // multidex
    //room
    implementation 'androidx.room:room-ktx:2.2.5'
    kapt "androidx.room:room-compiler:2.2.5"

    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:1.3.7"
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:1.3.0"
    //debug database
    debugImplementation 'com.amitshekhar.android:debug-db:1.0.6'
    implementation 'de.psdev.licensesdialog:licensesdialog:2.1.0'
    //support for APK less than 21
    implementation 'androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.1'
    // in app billing
    //implementation 'com.android.billingclient:billing-ktx:3.0.0'
    // Hilt
    implementation "com.google.dagger:hilt-android:2.28-alpha"
    kapt "com.google.dagger:hilt-android-compiler:2.28-alpha"

    implementation 'androidx.hilt:hilt-lifecycle-viewmodel:1.0.0-alpha01'
    kapt 'androidx.hilt:hilt-compiler:1.0.0-alpha01'
}
```

I am also using an external library and here is the `AndroidManifest.xml` file for it.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.github.barteksc.pdfviewer">

</manifest>
```

Here is the `build.gradle` for external library.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

ext {
    bintrayRepo = 'maven'
    bintrayName = 'android-pdf-viewer'

    publishedGroupId = 'com.github.barteksc'
    libraryName = 'AndroidPdfViewer'
    artifact = 'android-pdf-viewer'

    libraryDescription = 'Android view for displaying PDFs rendered with PdfiumAndroid'

    siteUrl = 'https://github.com/barteksc/AndroidPdfViewer'
    gitUrl = 'https://github.com/barteksc/AndroidPdfViewer.git'

    libraryVersion = '3.2.0-beta.1'

    developerId = 'barteksc'
    developerName = 'Bartosz Schiller'
    developerEmail = 'barteksch@boo.pl'

    licenseName = 'The Apache Software License, Version 2.0'
    licenseUrl = 'http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0.txt'
    allLicenses = ["Apache-2.0"]
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "3.2.0-beta.1"
    }

}

dependencies {
    implementation 'androidx.core:core:1.3.0'
    api 'com.github.barteksc:pdfium-android:1.9.0'
}

apply from: 'bintray.gradle'
```

Comment: And at which point in your app does the permission request appear? Have you checked if the permission is listed anywhere under app/build/intermediates/manifest_merge_blame_file/ ?

Comment: I am using Android API 22 as a test device. So when I open App info it says this app needs this permission.

Comment: Then it should definitely show up in the merged manifest. So what did the blame file say?

Comment: Yeah, it's in the merged manifest blame file. Should I remove that line from the merged manifest?

Comment: In that blame file you should be able to see where that permission declaration originated from (i.e. which dependency). Maybe you can find a newer version of that dependency that doesn't need the permission. Or maybe you can get rid of that dependency altogether.